# android.system.ErrnoException: read failed: EAGAIN in Android 5.0

Tags: java, android, xml

When I tested my app on Android 8.0 it's work just fine, but when I test it on Android 5.0 it keeps crashing every time I launch a new activity or I click in items of navigation drawer, I get the exception below, can you please help me, I am not getting anything from crash log telling where my application is crashing

```
02-18 11:16:28.934 800-1189/? E/NativeCrashListener: Exception dealing with report
    android.system.ErrnoException: read failed: EAGAIN (Try again)
        at libcore.io.Posix.readBytes(Native Method)
        at libcore.io.Posix.read(Posix.java:147)
        at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.read(BlockGuardOs.java:230)
        at android.system.Os.read(Os.java:364)
        at com.android.server.am.NativeCrashListener.consumeNativeCrashData(NativeCrashListener.java:240)
        at com.android.server.am.NativeCrashListener.run(NativeCrashListener.java:138)
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by removing this code from xml:

```
                android:shadowColor="@color/text_shadow_white"
                android:shadowDx="-2"
                android:shadowDy="-2"
                android:shadowRadius="1"
```

Comment: I think this is unrelated to your issue. The issue is related to file I/O.